onSubmit fires event only when losing focus
I know there is a lot of questions regarding this topic, but I have a specific question regarding javascript events.
I work on a html code, which has an input tag where the customer should enter an amount.
<input name="amount"
value="#{givenValue}"
converter="#{decimalConverter}"
styleClassInput="js-3-step-calc-amount-field"
onchange="rmc_doValueChange()"
required="true" />

The amount should always be rounded up to the next hundreds, e.g, customer enters 588,98, then it should send in the request 600.
Now it is with the onchange event, which of course does not work when an Enter is hit or the next button is pressed without losing focus on the input.
I have read that onkeyup is an option, but then it will update in every digit, which is not optimal.
Is there a way to call a certain method even when the focus is not lost on the input element and at the same time to not update by every digit or button press, because then when a user gives 876,99, it should round up after 8, 87, 876 and 876,9 too.
Any ideas?
Thank you a lot!

I think I'd just have it to the rounding on the submit too. BTW, your title doesn't seem to be related to your actual question.

onkeyup can be used to check which key was pressed, you don't have to run your rounding logic on every event, e.g: Detect the Enter key in a text input field (There are non-jQuery answers slightly down the page)
